# Continuum Anaconda Fedora 22 Linux path

Tags: bash, fedora, python, path

After an update to **Windows 10** I encounter problems in my dual boot system so I had to re-install **Fedora 22**.

So, starting with a fresh system I re-installed my work environment. The one installation that has been troublesome is **Continuum Anaconda Python**.

I followed the defaults, which meant it installed Fedora on `/root` directory.

No matter what I do I cannot launch any parts of the Anaconda package, even if as root I `cd` into `/root`.

Here is my `/root/.bashrc`:

```
# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Enable tab completion
source home/brian/git-completion.bash

# colors!
green="\[\033[0;32m\]"
blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"
purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"
reset="\[\033[0m\]"

# Change command prompt
source ~/git-prompt.sh
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
# '\u' adds the name of the current user to the prompt
# '\$(__git_ps1)' adds git-related stuff
# '\W' adds the name of the current directory
export PS1="$purple\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W $ $reset"

# added by Anaconda 2.3.0 installer
export PATH="/root/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Should I adjust my `PATH` ? I've tried everything I can think of.

Should I re-install Anaconda in another location?

Comment: what error do you get when you launch? the only reason that I can think of that root can not run python there is the execute bit is not set. Try as root `chmod 0755 /root/anaconda/bin/*` that might help, but I don't understand why the anaconda installation didnt took care of that.

Comment: **That was it!!!!** Thank you!  I would never have thought that anaconda would install as unexecutable.  Is there any way I can credit you with having given the answer?  You have saved me **so** much frustration.